# Unable to get the binding from textbox and bind combobox from another view model

Tags: wpf, mvvm, viewmodel

I am farily new to mvvm so bear with me. I have 2 View models which are inherited namely DBViewModel and PersonViewModel. i would like to add the person object in DBViewModel and bind 2 combobox with observablecollection in PersonViewModel.

```
 public class PersonViewModel
{
    private ICommand AddCommand ;

    public Person PersonI{get;set;}
    public ObservableCollection<Person> EmployeeList{ get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<String> OccupationList{ get; set; }

    public PersonViewModel()
    {
        PersonI = new Person();
        this.AddCommand = new DelegateCommand(this.Add);

        // get OccupationList and EmployeeList 
    }
    ......
}

 public class DBViewModel : PersonViewModel
{


    public PersonViewModel PersonVM { get; set; }

    public PersonViewModel()
    {
        PersonVM = new PersonViewModel();

    }
    ....
} 
<DataTemplate DataType='{x:Type viewModel:DBViewModel}'>
    <StackPanel>
          <TextBox Text="{Binding PersonI.Name}" />
    <ComboBox Name="cboccupation" ItemsSource="{Binding OccupationList}"
    DisplayMemberPath="Name"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" SelectedValuePath="Id"/>

    <Button Content="Add" Command="{Binding AddCommand}" />

   <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeeList}" CanUserAddRows="True">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Occupation">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding OccupationList}" 
                                  DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

    </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: PersonI is in PersonViewModel and hence you need do like this <TextBox Text="{Binding PersonVM.PersonI.Name}" />. Same thing has to be done for ComboBox

Answer (score 0):

if you want an easier approach I'm thinking you could set a datastore field using blend and bind both controls to that field.

Answer (score 0):

Your bindings are trying to bind to the properties `PersonI` and `OccupationList` on the `DBViewModel`, however those properties do not exist.

You need to point them to the `PersonVM.PersonI` and `PersonVM.OccupationList` instead.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding PersonVM.PersonI.Name}" />
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding PersonVM.OccupationList}" ... />
```

For your ComboBox binding inside the DataGrid, that probably will not work because the DataContext of each row in the Grid is a `Person` object (specified by the `DataGrid.ItemsSource`), and I don't think `Person` has a property called `OccupationList`.

You need to change the Source of your binding to use the object that has the OccupationList property.

For example, if your DataGrid was named `MyDataGrid`, the following binding for that ComboBox would work

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding 
              ElementName=MyDataGrid, 
              Path=DataContext.PersonVM.OccupationList}" ... />
```

Alternatively, you could use a RelativeSource binding to have it look for the parent DataGrid object without needing to specify a name

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding 
              RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, 
              Path=DataContext.PersonVM.OccupationList}" ... />
```

As a side note, you seem to be a bit confused about bindings and the `DataContext`. I like to blog about beginner WPF topics, and would recommend reading [What is this "DataContext" you speak of?](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2012/07/14/what-is-this-datacontext-you-speak-of/). I find it has helped many WPF beginners on this site understand the basic binding concept. :)

Comment: Thanks. I managed to get the value from textbox. But still having binding issue with the combobox in the datagrid.

Comment: You are binding the DataGrid to a list of `Person` objects, so the `DataContext` behind each row is a `Person`, and `Person` does not have a property called `OccupationList`. You need to change the Source for the binding to point to the right object. If you give your `DataGrid` a name, you can use `ElementName` in your binding to specify the data source for the binding, like `<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=MyDataGrid, Path=DataContext.PersonVM.OccupationList}" ... />`. Alternatively, you could use a `RelativeSource` binding to find the parent DataGrid. I'll update my answer.